# How do I create several ifs and elses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm new to javascript and I have this jQuery that replaces one image when the screen size is shrunk down to 480px. The thing is that I'd like to add a lot more images to do the same thing.
The only solution i got to work was to paste the code over and over again and replace the image values with new ones.
So how can I create several ifs and elses in the same script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

function imageresize() {  
var contentwidth = $('body').width();  
if ((contentwidth) < '480'){  
$('.spelguide').attr('src','bilder/480/spelguide.jpg');  
} else {  
$('.spelguide').attr('src','bilder/spelguide.jpg');  

}  
}  

imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads      

$(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized  
imageresize();  
});  

});
```

Comment: There's probably a CSS solution to this, though it will also require you to list out each size.

Comment: I suggest making them background images and swapping them out using CSS Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Indeed... e.g., @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){//assign bg rule}

Comment: I think you're looking for `else if`... See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for more info.

Comment: @ChristopherScott: Do browsers re-interpret media queries on resize?

Comment: @Zeta they sure do, check out my site for an example (resize the window): http://christopher-scott.com

Comment: Actually I think the OP is looking for some loop over a list of images. (Although I'd say media queries are the better solution.)

Comment: CSS3 media queries are the go-to tool for mobile responsive designs.

Comment: I don't think @user2141649 is looking for if..elseif solution

Comment: I would try to refine your logic (understand what work you are really trying to accomplish) and then use a LOOP to do it. See below for an example. Multiple if/else statements can get very cluttered, is redundant, and can become difficult to manage, especially if you're going to be working with a lot of images or adding more in the future.

Comment: Furthermore, I would avoid using CSS3 for altering img src attributes. While media queries are handy, CSS isn't designed to alter other HTML attributes other than style. Media queries would be good if you defined your img src with "background-image" - but you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want If..Else If..Else ? If so http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp gives an example.

Comment: yes something like that, though user brbcoding provided the best

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)!

Answer (score 2):

The usual pattern for chaining multiple if-else-ifs is doing something like

```
if (some_condition) {
  // do stuff
} else if (some_other_condition) {
  // do other stuff
} else if (another_condition) {
  // do another thing
} else {
  //default case
}
```

This is not just for Javascript. In most other programming languages with an if statement it will look similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Forget doing all that with javascript, let CSS do most of the work.
Just set a determining class on the body with javascript.

Javascript:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){  
   var body = $('body');
   var bodyWidth = body.width();
   body.toggleClass('size-480', bodyWidth < 480);
});
```

HTML:

```
   <img src="transparant.gif" class="img-spelguide" />
```

CSS:

```
img.img-spelguide {
   width: 400px; /*adjust accordingly*/
   height: 400px; /*adjust accordingly*/
   background: url(bilder/spelguide.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.size-480 img.img-spelguide {
   width: 200px; /*adjust accordingly*/
   height: 200px; /*adjust accordingly*/
   background: url(bilder/480/spelguide.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

You could still replace a lot of images using purely javascript, but CSS is better suited.

Note. if you can use @media-queries, please do so, thats the best option, however if you need to support legacy browsers, media-queries are obviously out =(

Lets throw in the javascript solution as well for good measure.

HTML:

```
<img src="bilder/spelguide.jpg" data-small="bilder/480/spelguide.jpg" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){  
   var body = $('body');
   var useSmall = body.width() < 480;
   $('img[data-small]').each(function(){
      var img = $(this);
      var big = img.data( 'big') || img.attr('src');
      var small = img.data('small');
      // make sure we have the original (big) src stored.
      img.data( 'big', big );
      img.attr( 'src', useSmall ? small : big );
   });
});
```

Still some room for optimisation.

Comment: Note that the OP wants to do this with multiple images. How are you going to define separate src url's with the background-image property for several different images? It's a rhetorical question - You'd have to assign ids to each image and manually set each background src. Not to mention, what you've provided is hacky.

Comment: First of all, all possible anwsers to this question, will by definition be 'hacky' when full browser coverage is required as there is no 'clean' way to do responsive images. The first solution requires an identifier and all src's are put inside a stylesheet. The 2nd solution accounts for multiple src's whilst assigning src's to the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do (assuming I understand your question correctly). The short answer, I would say is to: **Use a "for" loop**.

- First, I would give each image a UNIQUE id (instead of a class):

  - `<img id="example_img_id1" src="..." />`
- In my JavaScript, I would create a [JSON object](http://json.org) that has a (key : value) pair storing the (id : image_name) of each image (see below).
- Then, I would use a [for/in loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) that iterates over a JSON object.
- In your JSON object, add each of your unique img ids as the key and the name of the image as the value. Do this for all of the images that you have.

  ```
  // get the width of your body
  var contentwidth = $('body').width();  

  // key: value -----> '#img_id': 'src'
  var imgs = {
      '#example_img_id1' : 'imgname1.jpg',
      '#example_img_id2' : 'imgname2.jpg',
      '#example_img_id3' : 'imgname3.jpg',
      // ...
      '#example_img_idn' : 'imgname4.jpg'
  };

  // iterate over each image and create its new src
  for(var img in imgs) {
      // set the value of your src string
      var src = ''; 

      if(contentwidth < 480) { // if the screen size is less than 480
          src = '/bilder/480/' + imgs.img; // add the "/480/" directory
      } else { // anything 480 and larger
          src = '/bilder/' + imgs.img; // don't add "/480/"
      }

      // for every image in your JSON object (imgs),
      // it will create a jQuery object - $(img) - and
      // update its src attribute based on the screen width.
      $(img).attr('src', src);
  }
  ```

There's more than one way to skin a cat, and by no means is this the "best" or "most efficient" approach. Hopefully it at least points you in the right direction. Does this all make sense?